# Rectangle Box showing up in Andoid Studio

Tags: java, android

This is my first android studio app. When I run the app the rectangle box shows up in the center of the screen(Image attached). I remember that the box used to contain text earlier , saying "System UI not responding" , however earlier when I used to click on "WAIT" things used to continue on smoothly . Now , there are no buttons on the dialogue box as well. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.mywebapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

}
```

The rectangle box:

[image]

I came across this error when I tried to remove the "default" toolbox in the upper part of the screen , but I ended up with this.

Comment: There is nothing do with `code` because issue is from emulator. Is your PC spec is good for android studio as per https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-install-android-studio#1. If Yes then please try to delete emulator and recreate AVD.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. My device had the required specs , that wasn't a problem . The problem was with the emulator and when I reinstalled it , it worked well. Thanks a lot!